# Is it possible to call one event to another event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose i have event: 
 `protected void dpMyNoteBook_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)`,
Inside this event i want to  call another event name as : 
 `protected void ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin_Click(object sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs e)`.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to move the code that currently is in `ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin_Click` into a helper method and call that from `dpMyNoteBook_PreRender` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are normal functions that happen to be executed when an event is fired.
Yes.  (You can pass `null`s as the two parameters, unless your code actually uses the parameters)

However, it would probably be better to move the code to a separate method and call that method from both handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Events are just methods. You will need to create a new ImageClickEventArgs object and make sure it's populated properly (and you'll want to make sure sender is set to the image in question receiving the "click"), but it's just a method call.

```
ImageClickEventArgs e = new ImageClickEventArgs();
// set properties for e that may be relevant
// commandargument
// commandname
// whatever

ibtnPinMarkedRemovePin_Click(myImagesId, e);
```

Answer (score 0):

how to map the Selection_change event to DayRender event of the Calender control